Can't Connect to Data Source Login Timeout Expired Error Power Automate
I am running into this error in Power Automate Desktop when I try to establish a SQL connection to my work flow. I installed SQLNCLI11 yesterday.
Image of the error message
I have tried installing different versions of Power Automate but none have worked. Other versions say I don't have access to them, SQLNCLI11 at least tries to connect but it times out each time.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

I installed SQLNCLI11 yesterday. You installed something that is deprecated? That hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days? That Microsoft no longer even ships as of SQL Server 2022? Why aren't you using the modern and supported Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server that's listed on the Data Ling properties' provider tab by default?
